# XDM loops while given correct username and password

Tags: arch-linux, display-manager, xdm

I just installed XDM to set up a proper login screen on Archlinux, but it seems I did it wrong.
Indeed, XDM starts and prompt a thing I guess is the default login screen, but when I enter my password/username, it fades for a bit then pops again, despite the IDs being the right ones, and thus I can't access my session or anything. Is there any way to bypass XDM, involving not to chroot in the install via a bootable USB ?

Thanks

Comment: Do `xdm -error error_log_file` to debug if the error is really in xdm. The session setup process is fairly complicated, there are multiple ways for this to go wrong with user or system session settings when xdm works successfully.

Comment: Does this implies to access my session, or at least a terminal ? Because I currently unable to access any x)

Comment: If your current problem is "I cannot change anything", use Ctrl-Alt-Fn (some distros use F1, some F7, no idea what Archlinux does) to change to a virtual terminal where you can log in in text mode. Then you can look at the logs, and change your installation of XDM to provide logs if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your current problem is "I cannot change anything", use Ctrl-Alt-Fn (some distros use F1, some F7, no idea what Archlinux does) to change to a virtual terminal where you can log in in text mode. Then you can look at the logs, and change your installation of XDM to provide logs if necessary.

Thanks dirkt!